# Define an array in SailsJS 1.0 Model

Tags: sails.js, waterline

We have been running an app on sailsJS 0.12 -
once 1.0 was released ran through the upgrade process and upgraded

previously, some of the models were supporting "array" type, it's no longer supported. what's the alternative to this ? it's not covered in sample app or the documentation

model I have is :

```
module.exports = {
attributes: {
    provider: 'string',
    uid: 'string',
    email: 'string',
    name: 'string',
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',    
    password: 'string',    
    projects: {
      collection: 'project',
      via: 'owner'
    },
    creditsHistory:{
      collection: 'creditsHistory',
      via: 'owner'
    },    
    userRoles: {type: 'array', defaultsTo : [roles.USER]}
  },
```

supported types in sails 1.0 are : https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes

there isn't any example or sample on what to replace the array type with 
sails 0.12 supported types:
https://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes

does anyone has any idea on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like that:

```
'coordinate': {
      'type': 'json',
      'required': true,
    },
```

Or you can use it like this :

```
'cost_price': {
      'type': 'ref',
      'columnType': "double"

    },
```

in `colunmType` you can define database colunm type

Comment: after posting I was fiddling with it, got it to work - thanks for this though